# Why does ASP.NET MVC assumes that view will have matching input and output types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET MVC (or rather Html.Helpers and base page implementation) assumes that there will be one type for both rendering and posting (namely Model).

This is a violation of [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), isn't it?

I am tempted to derive my Edit views (those that have different render-data, and post-data) from a custom `EditPageBaseView<TViewModel, TFormData>`.

The problem is I want my validation and post work against FormData instance (stored inside ViewModel), but MVC assumes that entire ViewModel will be POSTed back.

1. Is there an OOB way to facilitate that? (I didn't find one if there is).
2. Is it a bad idea (in concept) to have separate data types for different operations exposed by a service (a view in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to follow the CQRS model when constructing my view models. All rendering is done with `ViewModel` classes and all posting back is done with `Command` classes. Here's a contrived example. Let's say we have a View with a small form for creating users.

The `ViewModel` and `Command` classes looks like this:

```
public abstract class ViewModel {}

public abstract class Command: ViewModel

public class CreateUserViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}

public class CreateUserCommand : Command
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}
```

The `UserController` creates a `CreateUserViewModel` as the model for the `Get` request and expects a `CreateUserCommand` for the `Post` request:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    // this should be created by a factory of some sort that is injected in
    var model = new CreateUserViewModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(CreateUserCommand command)
{
    // validate and then save the user, create new CreateUserViewModel and re-display the view if validation fails
}
```

Model binding takes care of ensuring that the properties of the Posted `CreateUserCommand` are populated properly, even though the Get View is bound to a `CreateUserViewModel`.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing. But _my_ _problem_ is that Html.ValidationMessageFor or Html.TextBoxFor assume view model type, not command view model type, so whole MVC mindset is in conflict with CQRS in this aspect. How do _you_ write Html.ValidationMessageFor? (example please).

Comment: I wouldn't have said so. The View gets rendered as a result of a query request and is bound to a `ViewModel`. This is the case regardless of whether it's an initial render or re-rendering as a result of validation failure. The view will always be bound to a `ViewModel` because a `Command` is created during a `HttpPost` and only exists from the boundary of the Controller Action method through to the data store, not within the View itself. All you're ever really posting back to the server is a bunch of form values that are rehydrated into an object via model binding.

Comment: I've just stumbled into this problem. To get client-side validation, I have to put the DataAnnotations on the `ViewModel`. To get server-side validation I have to put the DataAnnotations on the `Command`. Not very dry... What we need is `EditorFor(command => command.DestinationField, Model.SourceField)` which would be an epic change...

Answer (score 0):

They don't have to match, but they do match by default.

If you don't want them to match, you can specify a different model in your Form or ActionLink:

***Example of a Mismatch using Razor and C#:***

**Index.chtml:**

```
@model FirstModel

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "ControllerName", new { ParameterName = new SecondModel { First = "First", Second = "Second" } }, FormMethod.Post)) {
<input type="submit" value="Submit Button" />
}
</div>
```

**The Controller:**

```
public class ControllerName : Controller {

public ActionResult Index() {
return View(new FirstModel());
}

public ActionResult Action(SecondModel ParameterName) {
return View() // Where to now?
}
```

Comment: all validation methods and Id creation methods work against model type declared with @model